# php pass variables between pages

Tags: php

I'm trying to send this varabile from one page to another but there is no value in it when I send it

I stored the value in compInfo.php

in compInfo2.php

```
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['savebutton'])) {
            $company = new copmany();
            $copmnae = $_POST['CName'];
            $COMPNAME = $copmnae;
      ?>
```

I dont know whats wrong

```
  <a href='compInfo2.php?$copmnae=$GLOBALS["COMPNAME"]' > شاهد سيرتك الذاتية من هنا </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont really understand the problem but this is suspicious :

```
<a href='compInfo2.php?$copmnae=$GLOBALS["COMPNAME"]' > شاهد سيرتك الذاتية من هنا </a>
```

should be

```
echo  "<a href='compInfo2.php?CName={$COMPNAME}' > شاهد سيرتك الذاتية من هنا </a>";
```

or

```
<a href='compInfo2.php?CName=<?php echo $COMPNAME ?>' > شاهد سيرتك الذاتية من هنا </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

> `<a href="compInfo2.php?CName=<?php echo $GLOBALS['COMPNAME'];?>"> شاهد سيرتك الذاتية من هنا </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You also trying to send a $_GET data to the second file, then getting it there as a post data.

so if you want to keep it as get data, you should change $copmnae = $_POST['CName'];

to

```
 $copmnae = $_GET['CName'];
```

beside converting compInfo2.php?$copmnae=$GLOBALS["COMPNAME"] to

```
 compInfo2.php?CName=<?=$GLOBALS["COMPNAME"]?>
```

note the compnae name difference, because over in the second file you are getting the wrong name from the one you are sending.